# Delete rows in a table, but preserve rows with FK contraints

Tags: sql, sql-server, delete-row

I need to delete rows in a table, such as

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_X WHERE COL_A = 0
```

But I want to not delete any row that can have a constraint violation, and I need to know what rows have this violation...

I know that I can do joins with the relation tables, but i want to know if there exists any generic way to know what lines upon delete will have a constraint violation.

Comment: Please specify what database system you will be using like SQL 2008, MySQL, Oracle etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use JDBC, there is a Metadata function named GetExportedKeys()

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getExportedKeys%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Using that, you first get the Foreign Key constraints. Using that information, you construct a Join Statement to catch the violations. You run the statement to get the actual rows that would violate the constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may help you:

/*
Table X is the child table
Table Y is the parent table
*/

DELETE FROM TABLE_X where Y_ID not in (SELECT Y_ID FROM TABLE_Y)

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic way. You need to use joins (or generate joins at runtime from metadata which is generic but not built-in).

Comment: You can create the specific Join in a generic manner using the getExported keys, no?

Comment: As this is SQL Server I'd use sys.foreign_keys

Answer (score 0):

You can check the system tables, parse the constraints and use them to build the JOINs dynamically. This is not going to be easy.

Another way would be to delete the rows one by one (`SELECT` all the IDs, then delete each row using its primary key value). The `DELETE` operations that fail are those deleting a line with a constraint.

Do that inside a transaction and rollback at the end, so you don't actually delete the lines.

By the way, I don't recommend this practice, it's weird and inefficient. But it will work.

Answer (score 0):

DElete from x where 
col = 0
and
primarykey not in (
PrimaryKey
from x
Inner Join Y on x.FKey = Y.PrimaryKey
)